# Image::PNG::Libpng: "libpng error: Call to NULL write function"

Tags: perl, libpng

I have some code that should modify the tEXt or zTXt chunk of a PNG file with the Perl bindings of the libpng.

Code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper qw(Dumper);
use Image::PNG::Libpng qw(read_png_file write_png_file) ;


my $lpng = read_png_file ("testimg.png");

my @cmdAr = ();
for(my $i=0; $i<10; ++$i){
  push(@cmdAr, {compression => Image::PNG::Libpng::PNG_TEXT_COMPRESSION_zTXt ,
                key => sprintf("par_%02i",$i),
                text => sprintf("%06i", $i*$i)
               }
      );
}
print STDERR Dumper(\@cmdAr);
$lpng->set_text (\@cmdAr);
$lpng->write_png_file ("testimg2.png");
```

but the code fails at the write function with:

> libpng error: Call to NULL write function

Any hints about how to fix this? The files exists and the process also has write access.

My Perl version (latest Strawberry Perl):

> This is perl 5, version 26, subversion 0 (v5.26.0) built for
>   MSWin32-x86-multi-thread-64int

Version of the libpng module:

> cpan -D Image::PNG::Libpng

```
CPAN: CPAN::SQLite loaded ok (v0.211)
Database was generated on Thu, 15 Jun 2017 10:43:51 GMT

Image::PNG::Libpng
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    CPAN: Module::CoreList loaded ok (v5.20170530)
(no description)
    B/BK/BKB/Image-PNG-Libpng-0.43.tar.gz
    C:\strawberry-perl\perl\site\lib\Image\PNG\Libpng.pm
    Installed: 0.43
    CPAN:      0.43  up to date
    Ben Bullock (BKB)
    bkb@cpan.org
```

Comment: Do you have the correct version of libpng?

Comment: @simbabque I have the one that was installed along with the cpan-package

Comment: @simbabque the png-chunks are named `tEXt` and `zTXt` so it was correct before the edit

Comment: Oh, sorry about that. There were more capital letter typos, so I figured that one was just a typo too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The author of the module pointed me to the following function documentation:
https://metacpan.org/pod/Image::PNG::Libpng#write_png_file
that says:

> $png must be the object created by "create_write_struct", so
>   "read_png_file" followed by a call to this does not work.

`$png->copy_png` can be used to create a `write`-able structure.

So inserting a `$lpng = $lpng->copy_png();` before calling `set_text` results in the expected behaviour.

Complete (and cleaned) code for reference:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Image::PNG::Libpng qw(read_png_file write_png_file) ;



my @txts = ({compression => Image::PNG::Libpng::PNG_TEXT_COMPRESSION_zTXt,
             key          => "myImportentTextData",
             text         => "fooBar"
            });

my $png = read_png_file ("testimg.png");

$png = $png->copy_png();  #< this is important!

$png->set_text (\@txts);
$png->write_png_file ("testimg2.png");
```